# Webpack 4 configuration with React

Tags: reactjs, reload, webpack-4

How can I reload the application automatically in development mode with Webpack 4?
At the moment, I tried this script but it does not work:

```
"scripts": {
 "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
 "build": "webpack --mode production"}
```

Comment: You need to use --hot. If you want the page to automatically reload, please use something like react-hot-loader.

Comment: I also tried but it doesn't work. It reload on the console but not on the browser

Comment: You need to add React-hot-loader.

Answer (score 2):

Need to enable the `hot` property for `webpack-dev-server`. Read more in [docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-hot).

Use from CLI in the package scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --hot"
}
```

Use inside the `devServer` config object:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    // other configs: entry, output, module, plugins, etc.
    devServer: {
        hot: true
    }
};
```

Also, you can check this [Webpack-Demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) project using **Webpack 4** and **React**.